# How long is brewed coffee fresh for and what does that blinking light mean at Starbucks?

Tags: brewing-process, starbucks

I asked a Starbucks barista what the blinking light is for on the brewed coffee and he said is starts blinking 15 minutes after the coffee is brewed.

This makes no sense to me as they would have to brew coffee 4 times an hour which they obviously do not do because it would be ludicrous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blinking light is set on a timer for 30 minutes.  Unlike many coffee shops and pots there is no heater.

Heating is not good for coffee freshness and this is another reason the coffee should not sit for more than minutes.

Comment: Please elaborate the heating comment. Aside from that, this doesn't seem to add anything to the existing answer. Instead of reposting an existing answer, please consider up voting and accepting the existing answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The blinking light means it has been sitting there for 30 mins.

Starbucks Baristas do in fact brew coffee every 15 mins and are supposed to dump the coffee when the light blinks.

source: a starbucks barista

Comment: Do you know how long the brew time is.  That is after they hit the button, how long does it take the block to fill up?